# What is the logic behind this code? It is actually a code to print the star i.e. * in the form of the right angled triangle in C language

Tags: c, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 1; i <= a; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
      {
          printf("* ");

      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

What is the logic behind this code? It is actually a code to print the star i.e. * in the form of the right angled triangle in C language. So what is the actual logic behind this code. Can anyone please explain this to me.

Comment: I am sure, you can figure this out yourself. Look at how often the inner loop iterates based on the current iteration of the outer loop. let's say, i = 2, how many '*' will be printed in the inner loop? what happens when i = 3 and so on?

Comment: Do you understand how nested for loop works? This is a simple case of nested for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the pattern carefully you will find that stars are in increasing order of rows (i.e. 1 star in first row, followed by 2 stars in second and so on).

Step by step descriptive logic to print right triangle star pattern.

1. Input number of rows to print from user. Store it in a variable say N.
2. To iterate through rows run an outer loop from 1 to N with loop structure for(i=1; i<=N; i++).
3. To iterate through columns run an inner loop from 1 to i with loop structure for(j=1; j<=i; j++). Inside the inner loop print star.
   4.After printing all columns of a row move to next line i.e. print new line.